# Kendo Grid Offline Read and fallback server read if online

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mobile

In my app, I want to load data if it is offline or online for my user. If it is offline, it should pull recent data from indexed Db and if it is online it should fetch from server URL. How can we achieve this fallback mechanism?
I am looking for an approach where I will load grid using cached data from indexed DB and then overwrite it with server side data. so I will have some data for the user always irrespective of it whether  online/offline.

Is this approach possible to design?
Please suggest.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the offline mode of the kendo DataSource? https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/offline

Comment: yes, its good, but am not sure whether it will cache its initial data second time user opens the app? Because I want the app to work in offline mode, so that there will be some data always and when he comes online it will be replaced by the new data. Thatswhy i am looking for indexed DB approach.

Comment: Or is it possible kendo can store its data locally and available to user the next session

Comment: By default, it uses the browsers local storage so it should work even after closing/reopening the browser; it sounds like you'd need to make sure the datasource is in offline mode when the app first launches, so it goes to local storage first.  And only go 'online' when you need to sync data.

Comment: The storage mechanism is [pluggable](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/offline?_ga=2.239923270.473333608.1595430677-1155300249.1542276053#using-custom-offline-storage) as well, so perhaps you could use that to write to a DB instead?